# How to profile a program with llvm tools with llvm 3.5 or greater?

Tags: llvm, pgo

I am looking into using llvm tools to generate block level profile of small programs. It looks like in older versions this was as simple as running:

```
perl utils/profile.pl -block program.bc
```

How is profiling done in newer versions of LLVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Clang and llvm-profdata

Visit the Clang User's Manual [profile with instrumentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#profiling-with-instrumentation)

llvm doc [llvm-profdata](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-profdata.html)

In summary:

1. Build an instrumented version of the code

   ```
   clang -O2 -fprofile-instr-generate code.c
   ```
2. Run the instrumented executable to get the profile data file

   ```
   ./a.out
   ```
3. Combine profiles from multiple runs and format the files by running

   ```
   llvm-profdata merge *.profraw -output=code.profdata
   ```
4. Build the code again

   ```
   clang -O2 -fprofile-instr-use=code.profdata code.c
   ```

(Optional?) 5. Display the profile counters for this file and for any of the specified function(s)

```
    llvm-profdata show -all-functions code.profdata
```